# Visualizing 2d data in a certain way

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, visualization, matlab-figure

I need to make an image from some 2d data that consist of 349 rows and 4007 columns. In my attempt below, I just use the first 300 columns.

```
clf;
B = importdata('beta.txt');
Bd = detrend(B(:,1:300),0); % remove the zero offset
d  = 10000;                 % vertical spacing
Bs = Bd;                    % copy of the original data

initOffset = Bs(1,1);

for i = 1 : size(Bs,2) % loop adding constant to each column
    Bs(:,i) = Bs(:,i) - initOffset + (i-1) * d ; %subtract the offset from each
end
```

The image that I desire looks something like this:

[image: Figure 1]

But this is the image that I get when I make it using: `plot(Bs, 'k');` looks like this:

[image: Figure 2]

I believe the image needs to undergo normalization to 0-255 and is created using grayscale (other suggestions are appreciated). This is a sample data from the text file:

```
4855    4641    4891    4791    4812    4812    4927    4833    4768    4832
4827    4766    4862    4745    4767    4785    4867    4840    4918    4735
6676    5075    6903    6879    6697    6084    4896    4758    5658    5546
7340    6829    7678    7753    7263    6726    7386    6726    5798    6168
6176    6237    6708    6737    6316    5943    6320    5962    5706    5817
12014   10467   10915   10914   10124   10642   10379   10700   10410   10055
8251    7538    7641    7619    7269    7658    7477    7579    7376    7201
6456    6105    6132    6136    5921    6227    6074    6011    6009    5932
5519    5287    5330    5376    5255    5237    5296    5287    5187    5138
4904    4784    4835    4855    4794    4758    4841    4756    4767    4772
4553    4527    4472    4592    4469    4455    4470    4480    4394    4340
4298    4323    4291    4293    4221    4238    4284    4213    4125    4094
4167    3957    4089    3991    3938    3907    3986    3875    3878    3923
3789    3721    3777    3777    3643    3596    3672    3664    3725    3652
3736    4615    3639    3582    3638    3550    3411    3302    3427    3444
4413    5286    4248    3998    4370    4199    3821    3750    3738    4279
5994    6896    6134    5548    6102    6161    5242    5356    5361    6063
8506    9020    7841    8060    8663    8941    7497    7815    7793    8710
12347   12302   10639   11151   12533   12478   11253   11312   11198   12287
18859   18175   15035   15938   18358   18160   15989   15665   15683   18506
27106   26261   22613   24069   27015   27114   23307   23712   23854   23966
32767   32601   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32712
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767   32767
26416   26459   32767   32767   26308   26945   32767   19586   32767   32767
6523    6900    13327   16665   6616    6477    12799   -8608   13109   15553
-14233  -14011  -8554   -5649   -13956  -13858  -8707   -21817  -8875   -6927
-28128  -26784  -26157  -24055  -27875  -28374  -26639  -30353  -27054  -25518
-28775  -27905  -30348  -26285  -28915  -29066  -32768  -32396  -32714  -30599
-20635  -19776  -21144  -21548  -22107  -22759  -26599  -27908  -24334  -22628
```

Comment: You sure you need to use plot? looks like the output you want is easier with 'image' or 'imagesc' and using the greyscale colormap

Comment: how can i get the image with greyscale colormap?

Comment: One option is imagesc(data); colormap(gray);  check documentation for more options https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html

Comment: So what exactly are you having a difficulty with? Normalizing the data? Setting a grayscale colormap? Choosing the correct plotting function? Being told that your axes are switched? It's good that you provided a sample of your data (though it would be easier to say that it was `int16`), however none of us will ever be able to reproduce the plots with such a small subset of the data. You might want to upload the text file somewhere or use an image format that can hold negative values (I believe _tiff_ is such a format). I'll wait for more information.

Comment: @Dev-iL this is the text file containing all the data https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zfzpz37tbd6tzm/beta.txt?dl=0 . I have difficulty in making the image, i presume specifically, setting up the grayscale colormap. I have looked at surf and imagesc function and the latter seems to be handling mostly 3d data. btw thanks for the comment!

Comment: @hphys try Noels code, as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you're working with MATLAB, you might as well store your data as an image and not text - which is both more meaningful and more compact. You can use the following code to save it as a 16-bit `png`:

```
B = importdata('beta.txt');
imwrite(uint16(B - double(intmin('int16'))), 'beta.png');
```

Which results in this:

[image]

You can even verify that no information got lost by loading the image right from this webpage using:

```
V = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4NUA.png');
assert(isequal(B, double(V) + double(intmin('int16'))));
```

---

Moving on to your actual question, it appears that the `349` dimension corresponds to "time", which means it should be the `y` axis. Since the values should increase from top to bottom, the [`axis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#input_argument_d119e60567) command is not necessary. Therefore, all you really need to do is simply display the image, [just as Noel said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258377/#comment83501544_48258377):

```
figure(); imagesc(B); colormap('gray');
```